# 'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command on Windows 8

Tags: c++, mingw

I am trying to use MinGW on Windows, I read many posts here but still I cannot solve the problem. I am getting the following message:

```
'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command ...
```

I have already include in my PATH I have include:

```
 C:\MinGW\bin;
```

I tried also `setx` and `set` but maybe not properly to set the g++.

My PATH is

```
PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32
\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-St
atic;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\M
icrosoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0
\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Bi
nn\;  C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin; C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe; C:\MinGW\bin\"g++.exe";     C:\MinGW\bin\g++;
```

I am using Windows 8 and I restarted my PC after setting the PATH.

Comment: What happens when you specify the full path? i.e. `C:\MinGW\bin\g++`? If it still can't find it MinGW is probably installed under another path.

Comment: @user657267 I can see the file on `C:\MinGW\bin\g++` and when I am trying to run g++ from its file I am getting `g++: fatal error: no input files` obviously because I dont specify any file. So I think g++ is properly installed.

Comment: @sashoalm I have already read that and I mentioned it in my post that I have read it. Since it doesnt work for me why it is a duplicate?

Comment: In that case your path is somehow to blame. What does `echo %PATH%` display?

Comment: @Avraam Not understanding a previous question does not make yours different. If your question is the same, word for word, then it's a duplicate. If it's not, you need to provide concrete reasons why your question is different. Remember duplicates are based solely on similarity of the questions, not on the answers. It doesn't matter what answers the previous question has, do doesn't have, only that yours is the same.

Comment: @user657267 I edit my post including the PATH.

Comment: Here is a link that shows how to setup MinGW on Windows: http://www.zeusedit.com/zforum/viewtopic.php?t=6957

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path is rather a mess.  For example the entry that should be `C:\MinGW\bin` has several leading spaces.  Windows treats all characters between the semi-colons in a path as significant characters - you need to remove those extraneous spaces.

You also have the following items in the path (some with leading spaces), which should probably be removed:

```
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe
C:\MinGW\bin\"g++.exe"
C:\MinGW\bin\g++
```

Note that `PATH` entries should not include the executable file itself, only the directory that contains the executable files you want the OS to locate in a PATH search. Also, quotes should not be included in a `PATH` entry; similar to spaces, the code that uses the path will treat them as actual parts of the directory name to search.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. I didnt expect that spaces is a problem.

Comment: Spaces are valid characters in a file name just like any other so "file" and " file" are both valid names, even if one is more difficult to create than the other.